# How do I tell if a C integer variable is signed?

Tags: c, gcc, integer, c-preprocessor

As an exercise, I'd like to write a macro which tells me if an integer variable is signed.  This is what I have so far and I get the results I expect if I try this on a char variable with gcc -fsigned-char or -funsigned-char.

```
#define ISVARSIGNED(V) (V = -1, (V < 0) ? 1 : 0)
```

Is this portable?  Is there a way to do this without destroying the value of the variable?

Comment: This is a curious problem, but I'm more far more intrigued by what your intended use for this information is.  Any chance of sharing?

Comment: @jeffamaphone: Actually, this is where templates shine in C++.

Comment: @stephentyrone - I think it's just curiosity, based on the first three words of the OP's question. I can't exactly imagine a practical application for this kind of information.

Comment: @Chris @stephentyrone this is an exercise from the book Expert C Programming by Peter Van Der Linden

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#define ISVARSIGNED(V)  ((V)<0 || (-V)<0 || (V-1)<0)
```

doesn't change the value of V. The third test handles the case where V == 0.

On my compiler (gcc/cygwin) this works for `int` and `long` but not for `char` or `short`.

```
#define ISVARSIGNED(V) ((V)-1<0 || -(V)-1<0)
```

also does the job in two tests.

Comment: Best I've seen yet.  Portable, standard-conforming, accurate as far as I can see.

Comment: Doesn't distinguish between signed/unsigned short and char. Those types are promoted to int when evaluating a < == > expression.

Comment: If you want to make it work for `short` and `char` you could probably cast the variable to `char` before using it. That should handle most overflow issues. I think...

Answer (score 5):

```
#define ISVARSIGNED(V) ((-(V) < 0) != ((V) < 0))
```

Without destroying the variable's value. But doesn't work for 0 values.

What about:

```
#define ISVARSIGNED(V) (((V)-(V)-1) < 0)
```

Comment: #define ISVARSIGNED(V) ((-V < 0) != (V < 0))

Comment: yeah I shouldn't have C&Pd that redundant stuff ;-)

Comment: @plinth, you forgot the "extra" parens around 'V' which make it safe from insane macro expansions

Comment: Fails for V == 0.  Also, if V has the most negative possible value, it's likely to fail, since there is no positive equivalent.

Comment: #define ISVARSIGNED(V) ((-(V) < 0) != ((V) < 0))  Noted.  Interestingly enough, this test fails on V == 0.

Comment: The second version works for 0, INT_MIN, UINT_MAX and INT_MAX in appropriate types.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using GCC you can use the `typeof` keyword to not overwrite the value:

```
#define ISVARSIGNED(V) ({ typeof (V) _V = -1; _V < 0 ? 1 : 0 })
```

This creates a temporary variable, `_V`, that has the same type as `V`.

As for portability, I don't know. It  will work on a two's compliment machine (a.k.a. everything your code will ever run on in all probability), and I believe it will work on one's compliment and sign-and-magnitude machines as well. As a side note, if you use `typeof`, you may want to cast `-1` to `typeof (V)` to make it safer (i.e. less likely to trigger warnings).

Comment: In C++, it's guaranteed to work by the Standard, regardless of the integer representation (for n bits, the value is 2^n - 1).  I don't have the C standard handy (either of them).

Comment: Me neither, but I recall reading on Wikipedia (the source of all things true :P ) that the C standard allows the three representations I listed. Not that anyone uses them anymore...

Answer (score 2):

This simple solution has no side effects, including the benefit of only referring to v once (which is important in a macro). We use the gcc extension "typeof" to get the type of v, and then cast -1 to this type:

```
#define IS_SIGNED_TYPE(v)   ((typeof(v))-1 <= 0)
```

It's <= rather than just < to avoid compiler warnings for some cases (when enabled).

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to all the "make it negative" answers:

```
#define ISVARSIGNED(V) (~(V^V)<0)
```

That way there's no need to have special cases for different values of V, since ∀ V ∈ ℤ, V^V = 0.

Answer (score -1):

A distinguishing characteristic of signed/unsigned math is that when you right shift a signed number, the most significant bit is copied. When you shift an unsigned number, the new bits are 0.

```
#define HIGH_BIT(n) ((n) & (1 << sizeof(n) * CHAR_BITS - 1))
#define IS_SIGNED(n) (HIGH_BIT(n) ? HIGH_BIT(n >> 1) != 0 : HIGH_BIT(~n >> 1) != 0
```

So basically, this macro uses a conditional expression to determine whether the high bit of a number is set. If it's not, the macro sets it by bitwise negating the number. We can't do an arithmetic negation because -0 == 0. We then shift right by 1 bit and test whether sign extension occurred.

This assumes 2's complement arithmetic, but that's usually a safe assumption.

Comment: Do you have a source for these assumptions on the behavior of bit shifts?

Comment: The C99 standard (section 6.5.7) says a right shift of a signed, negative value is implementation defined. My interpretation is that there will be a sign extension on a 2's complement machine. Since C is not specific to 2's complement architectures, they won't come out and say this.

Comment: You would be more PC by using `CHAR_BITS` instead of the magic `8`. (Yes, I know, there's only a very few of us _not_ working on machines where a byte is 8bit. Still.)

Comment: @sbi Edited to use CHAR_BITS. I'm curious though: what machine are you working that doesn't have 8 bits per byte? And how many bits does it have? I know such systems existed a long time ago, but I didn't know any modern systems didn't have 8-bit bytes.

Comment: @sbi - If not using `CHAR_BITS` is a bad assumption, then relying on two's compliment is probably also a bad assumption. It all depends on how much effort you really want to put into technical correctness.

Comment: It is not guaranteed even on a 2's complement implementation that signed right shift is arithmetic. By all means say that this solution works on most implementations, on all implementation you've encountered, etc. But it's not a valid reading of the standard to say that right shift sign-fills on 2's complement machines. If the standard intended to specify that, then don't worry, it would :-)

Comment: @Jay: I'm working on PCs, and although over the years most of my code has been ported to many, many platforms, I don't believe there ever was one that didn't have an 8bit `char` type. `:)` That's why I wrote it would be more PC to do so. However, I suspect it might be that 16bit char types will be introduced while I'm still programming. (Hasn't .NET a 16bi `char`?)

Comment: @sbi: There are various DSPs with 16, 24(!) or 32 bit chars.

Comment: @onebyone: Thanks! I keep forgetting the emdedded world is strange and has all the strange things. `:)`

Answer (score -1):

Why on earth do you need it to be a macro?  Templates are great for this:

```
template <typename T>
bool is_signed(T) {
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized, "Specialize std::numeric_limits<T>");
    return std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed;
}
```

Which will work out-of-the-box for all fundamental integral types.  It will also fail at compile-time on pointers, which the version using only subtraction and comparison probably won't.

*EDIT*: Oops, the question requires C.  Still, templates are the nice way :P

Comment: a _C_ Integer, not a C++ Integer.